# how to find difference in keycode values for 3 and #

Tags: javascript, ios, keycode

String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) returns always 3 for 3 and # in iOS device. How to get identify this accordingly? 
I have tried using this function and it always returns 3.
Is there any function exists to get the appropriate key pressed

Comment: Instead of `onkeydown/up` use `onkeypress`, (or try to detect `e.shiftKey`?)

Comment: e.shiftkey will return false in iOS browser